# Android : Store and access all keyboard input on the phone

Tags: android, input, keyboard

Is there a way to store everything a person types using their smartphone keyboard in a local database on the phone and access it later on ?

Thanks

Edit:

I don't want to use this for immoral purposes, what I will do with it will require the user's consent.

Comment: A keylogger, sounds immoral

Comment: @Phil3992 I don't want to use it for immoral reasons, what I want to use it for will require the user's consent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using the [`AccessibilityService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#onKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)). The user has to explicitly turn it on in the Settings for obvious reasons. See the top of the page for setup instructions.

Otherwise the app would need to be open for it to be stored, which is how the keyboards do it.